# Isolation Mode and viewport rendering in 2.80

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view, workflow

Is there anyway to viewport render in isolation mode like in 2.79. Currently if you isolate an object and go to viewport render, it renders the whole scene rather than just the isolated object. All other view port modes like Lookdev and Eevee only render whats in isolation with the current lighting applied. This used to be really handy for working on  a single object.  The only workaround I have is shift-h to hide everything else but it also hides all lights.